# Why do i have to give the parent for creating a client?

Tags: java, network-programming, jframe, processing

I'm trying to make a small little client GUI for my project, which is supposed to get commands over the network by the client.

For the server I am using Processing because I need a good looking canvas since I want to project it with a beamer. But for the inputs, I don't want to use Processing because it does not feature buttons, dropdowns or textfields (or at least I found no lib for it).

Therefore I added the library of Processing to my eclipse IDE and used a Java lib for screens, buttons, and other stuff. I still need to use the `processing.net.Client` to support connections between my client and the server, but `processing.net.Client` wants to have the parent `PApplet` as an argument. Since I am not using processing for my display, I have no `PApplet` (I think I have a `JFrame` now). This is causing issues I can't fix right now.

```
 myClient = new Client(~Here should be a PApplet~,"127.0.0.1",port);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using Processing's [Network](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/index.html) library.

If so, the `Client` class requires a `PApplet` argument because the library was designed to be used from a Processing sketch. You can find more info in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/Client.html).

As for the why, you can take a look at the source for the `Client` class [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/java/libraries/net/src/processing/net/Client.java). It looks like the `Client` class uses the `PApplet` class for a few things, specifically setting up method callbacks.

You could create a dummy `PApplet` instance for your client. If you do this, make sure you define/call any necessary functions so the callbacks work.

Or you could use a more general networking library that doesn't require Processing.

> I don't want to use Processing because it does not feature buttons, dropdowns or textfields (or at least I found no lib for it).

Processing has several GUI libraries. Please see the [libraries page](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/).

Comment: I tried a Processing library for gui but that was not as easy as my old gui library. Therefore i just exported my sketch to IntelliJ and used another network library. Anyway thanks for ur help